# Question about Folland's proof of extension-of-premeasures theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L4en.png) is an excerpt from Folland's Real Analysis. I don't understand why the calculation $\nu (E)\leq \sum _n \nu (A_n)=\sum _n \mu_0(A_n)$ implies $\nu(E)\leq \mu (E)$. Why is this? The $A_n$ are not assumed disjoint or anything...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if we take the infimum of your last sum over all sequences $A_n$ whose union covers $E$, we get exactly $\mu^*(E)$ and so $\nu(E)\le\mu^*(E)$. But for $E\in\mathcal M$, we have $\mu^*(E)=\mu(E)$ (again by definition).